# Backup Jenkins log folder via ThinBackup

Tags: jenkins, backup

I want to backup all `.log*` files under `$JENKINS_HOME/logs` via thinBackups `Backup additional files` Feature. Folder structure is as follows:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/logs/
|-- health-checker.log
|-- slaves
|   |-- Slave\ 1
|   |   `-- slave.log
|   |-- Slave\ 2
|   |   `-- slave.log
|   `-- Slave\ 3
|       `-- slave.log
`-- tasks
    |-- Connection\ Activity\ monitoring\ to\ agents.log
    |-- Connection\ Activity\ monitoring\ to\ agents.log.1
    |-- Download\ metadata.log
    |-- Download\ metadata.log.1
    |-- Fingerprint\ cleanup.log
    |-- Fingerprint\ cleanup.log.1
    |-- Periodic\ background\ build\ discarder.log
    |-- Periodic\ background\ build\ discarder.log.1
    |-- Workspace\ clean-up.log
    |-- Workspace\ clean-up.log.1
    |-- telemetry\ collection.log
    |-- telemetry\ collection.log.1
```

What I have now is the following regex:

```
^(logs|tasks|.*\.log.*)
```

which catches the top level `health-checker.log` and also all logs below `tasks`. But how do I extend this regex to also include all logs from all slaves (Slave 1, Slave 2 and Slave 3)?

I tried the following regex

```
^(logs|tasks|.*\.log.*)^(logs|slaves|Slave\ 1|.*\.log.*)
```

which does not work. I also cannot find any further explanation for the regex formatting thinBackup is using.

P.S. Our security departement requires backup of all logs for the last 90 days.

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin is buggy when it comes to include and exclude regex. If you exclude `.*xml` it shouldn't backup any files ending in `xml` but some files (not all) are still backed up.